# how to move into next text box using onblur function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I move focus into the next text box using the onblur functionality provided by jQuery?

Please do not suggest that I am not using `tabindex`.

```
<ul class='tabs'>
                        <li><a id="ATab1" href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
                        <li><a id="ATab2" href='#tab2' >Tab 2</a></li>
                        <li><a id="ATab3" href='#tab3' >Tab 3</a></li>

                </ul>
                <div id='tab1'>
                        <h3>Section 1</h3>
                        Fisrt: <input type="textbox" />
                        <br />
                        Second: <input type="textbox" />
                        <br />
                        Third: <input type="textbox" />
                        <br />
                        Fourth: <input type="textbox" on blur() />
                </div>
                <div id='tab2'>
                        <h3>Section 2</h3>
                        Fifth: <input type="textbox" />
                        <br />
                        Sixth: <input type="textbox" />
                </div>
                <div id='tab3'>
                        <h3>Section 3</h3>
                        Seventh: <input type="textbox" />
                        <br />
                        Eighth: <input type="textbox" on blur() />
                </div>
                <div id='tab4'>
                <h3>Section 4</h3>
                        ninth: <input type="textbox" />
                        <br />
                        tength: <input type="textbox" on blur()  />
```

this is the demo: [this is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/YG94p/3/)

Comment: Just for the last ones? What should happen than? which one should be focused? Imagine you don't know nothing about the issue (*us*), now read your question again... do you understand it?

Comment: can you provide more details like you want to change a tab and focus to fifth textbox when user reached at last textbox of current tab?

Comment: @Joker, **NEVER** change the content of malfunctioning code.  Doing so can completely change the nature of the problem.  No spelling fixes, no capitalization fixes, and only ever fix whitespace if it's unreadable as-is.  The existing whitespace is excessive but entirely readable and did not need to be fixed.  You also left all of the spelling and grammar problems untouched.  Please only suggest *substantial* edits.

Comment: what are you doing on you `onBlur()` ???

Comment: i update the demo it is not going into textboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is code for you**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/CJgNH/)

Hope it helps you :)

Use input type="text" instead of textbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').focusout(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('input[type="text"]').first().focus()
});
});
```

Comment: this is not working. this is demo of the application taht i was created but it is not going into textboxes demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/YG94p/3/

Comment: See it working http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/YG94p/4/

You have added invalid type of input

<input type="text"> instead of type="textbox"
No matters what it does. I have updated your fiddle..

Hope it solves your issue. :)

Comment: thanks for reply But it is not going into textboxex. and my problem is when it is in last text box on pressing tab key it will move to next tabs'text box

Comment: i can't understand what are you saying

You are using on tab key goes on next tab

So where you foucs out it goes on next textbox ??

Comment: can u send me your contact no on user200bk at gmail com. i will tel u all the details.plz try to understand my problem

Comment: contact me on krunap1993@syncwebagency.com
Send me your question 
i will post perfect answer here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no input type textbox. Use input `type="text"`

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('blur',function(){
   $(this).next('input[type="text"]').focus();
});
```

Comment: i update the demo it is not going into textboxes http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/YG94p/3/

Answer (score 0):

you are writing it wrong, you may want to [read this](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) before moving ahead

```
<input type="text" onblur="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EQuyutu/5/edit)

```
var inputs = $('input:text');

inputs.blur(function(){
   inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+1 ).focus();
});
```

note the input HTML: `<input type="text" />`

Comment: @user3149053 *it is not going*... can you please explain it finally? In your demo one cannot even type a single character into that inputs...

Comment: try to understand my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521265/on-pressing-tab-it-is-not-moving-to-next-tab